# how to do this in action script

Tags: actionscript-3

Number type variable for eg xxxx=0.200000585858;

how do i convert xxxx value as 0.200?

Comment: You question is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

please see [Number::toFixed](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toFixed%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

This should also work. But your question wasn't specific on wether you wanted the number to be rounded or not.

```
Math.round(xxxx*1000)/1000
```